# Do I need to create the SQS in the same VPC as the ECS is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-vpc

I have a ECS cluster inside the VPC. ECS have to read from a SQS. So, do I need to create SQS in the same VPC for that to communicate? Also, if say, I wanted to communicate outside VPC, how can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQS queues do not belong to a specific VPC. There is no networking involved when creating/configuring a queue.

Access to SQS queues is entirely managed with IAM permissions.

With ECS, you will have to configure your task execution role properly. As an example, a policy like the following allows to send, receive and delete messages from a specific queue:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:<region>:<account>:<queue name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

See also [Authentication and Access Control for Amazon SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-authentication-and-access-control.html).

Answer (score 9):

While SQS is AWS Managed Service can be accessed via public internet endpoint directly without any VPC restrictions, from the perspective of ECS application interacting with SQS, I would advise to create VPC PrivateLink Endpoint to SQS which is going to save you from doing additional hop trip via Internet Gateway.

**If you don't create VPC Endpoint, the traffic is routed in below fashion.**

> AWS ECS App ----> NAT Gateway(If ECS is in private subnet of VPC otherwise this is not needed) ----> Internet Gateway ----> AWS SQS.

**If you do create VPC Endpoint to SQS, then the traffic will be something like below which removes hop of going through internet.**

> AWS ECS App ----> AWS SQS(Over PrivateLink)

Here is some documentation on how VPC endpoints work and some guide for creating VPC endpoint for SQS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-vpc-endpoints.html